# How to change ElementTree attribute keys?

Tags: attributes, key, elementtree

I want to change the attributes of an existing element, and not just the values, but add/remove/change the keys too.  For example,

```
<frame_geometry name="border" has_title="false"/>
```

I would like to add: rounded_top_left="5" etc...
Is modifying element attributes' keys after creation possible?

If not, perhaps I could use a workaround, something like storing all the element's attributes in a temporary dictionary and then creating a new element from that +/- any desired changes?
This solution is not desirable however because the elements I need to modify have several subelements also...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out. So simple.
Add new attribute:

```
element.attrib['newkey'] = 'newvalue'
```

will add an attribute to existing element.
To remove an existing attribute:

```
del element.attrib['unwanted_key']
```

As far as modifying existing keys, I still don't know if that's possible, but with add/remove you can easily work around.

Answer (score -1):

I've had success by iterating through the elements I was hoping for a .rename style function

```
 For element in XMLData:
     if element.tag = Searching:
         element.tag = "NewTag"
         #Now its element.NewTag
```